# Cambiar indice Array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo esta Array donde intento hacer que tenga un indice associativo

```
var test = [
                    [
                        "test",
                        "test2",
                        "test3",
                        true
                    ],
                    [
                        "test2",
                        "test3",
                        "test5",
                        true
                    ]]
```

Hecho esta funcion para hacer el cambio pero solo me lo hace con la primera, la segunda no lo llega a hacer, me cambia el indice en la primera solo.

```
function changeIndex(Valor){
        var TempArray=[];
        var ArrayFinal={};
        var columns = $("#test > thead > tr").closest('tr').find('th');
        $(columns).each(function(i, v){

             TempArray.push($(this).text());

        });
        for (var i = 0; i < Valor.length; i++) {
        //  console.log(Valor.length);
            for (var e = 0; e < Valor[i].length; e++) {
            console.log(i);
            ArrayFinal[TempArray[e]]=Valor[i][e];

            }   
        }


        //console.log(ArrayFinal);
        return ArrayFinal;
    }
```

Lo quiero hacer es que  de la Array que tengo, se modificie para tenerla asi,
La funcion me la hace pero solo me lo hace con una.

```
    (1) [
​
          0: {
​​
          TH1: "test"
​​
          TH2: "test2"
​​
          TH3: "test3"
​​
         TH4: ""
           }
       ]
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar lo que quieres hacer y por qué? Tu pregunta no es muy clara y quizá se pueda simplificar lo que quieres...

Comment: esto ocurre porque un objeto no puede tener propiedades duplicadas. Cuando estas creando el `ArrayFinal` las propiedades se sobreescriben porque estas volviendo setear una propiedad que ya existe en dicho objeto.

Comment: entonces no puedo tener la array con indice associativo ? que es lo que intento hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas cambiar tu función para que el índice sea la clave y crear un objeto para cada índice.

```js
function changeIndex(Valor) {
    var TempArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]; // para testear he puesto valores estáticos
    var ArrayFinal = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < Valor.length; i++) {
        ArrayFinal[i] = {};
        //  console.log(Valor.length);
        for (var e = 0; e < Valor[i].length; e++) {
            console.log(i);
            // Aqui se setea el valor para cada indice
            // Estoy accediendo al objeto por indice y seteando lo valores
            //  ArrayFinal[i] me devueleve el objeto que inicializado fuera del loop
            // y le creo las propiedades con los valores que hay en TempArray
            ArrayFinal[i][TempArray[e]] = Valor[i][e];

        }
    }


    //console.log(ArrayFinal);
    return ArrayFinal;
}

console.log(changeIndex([
    ["test", "test2", "test3", true],
    ["test2", "test3", "test5", true]
]));
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, ya me lo muestra correctamente.